# How do I use cut to separate by multiple whitespace?

Tags: text-processing, columns, cut

I have this input, which is displayed in columns. I would like to get the second last column with the numbers of this sample:

```
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  1.00 MBytes  8.39 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   768 KBytes  6.29 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec   512 KBytes  4.19 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec   256 KBytes  2.10 Mbits/sec
...
```

If I use

```
cut -d\  -f 13
```

I get

```
Mbits/sec
6.29
4.19
2.10
```

because sometimes there are additional spaces in between.

Comment: The last column is `Mbits/sec`, is that what you want or the 2 last columns?

Comment: I only want to get the 2nd last column, only the numbers

Comment: I was looking for the same thing for `wg show all latest-handshakes` which *looks* like multiple whitespace for separator (I don't really know) and it turns out that the default separator (whatever that is) worked fine! So `<cmd> | cut -f 3` worked nicely.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142735/how-to-specify-more-spaces-for-the-delimiter-using-cut#

Answer (score 277, accepted):

If we use `tr` command along with *squeeze* option (`-s` flag ) to convert all multiple consecutive spaces to a single space and then perform `cut` operation with space as delimiter – we can access the required column carrying the numbers:

```
< file tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 8
```

Comment: BSD cut offers `-w` for such cases!

Comment: @Michael-O Nice! I'm using `cut` from GNU coreutils on Arch Linux and it lacks such an option.

Comment: this can be done without `cat`: `tr -s ' ' file | cut -d ' ' -f 8`

Comment: My version of `tr` (8.30) does not accept a file, so I need to redirect the stream. The command becomes: `tr -s ' ' < file | cut -d ' ' -f 8` (mind the `<`).

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre Indeed.  I tried to edit the post to make that correction, but SO said "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?", and I refuse to play games to get around that, so the wrong answer stands, at least for now.

Comment: `tr -s ' '` is an answer I was NOT looking for NOW but I was looking a few moments ago and finding only `sed` options to replace multiple white spaces into one! Thank you!

Comment: It's funny how sometimes the little people do more work more quickly with a fewer words than all the "important" people put together. Here's `tr` fixing a common use-case with 9 characters.

Comment: Ftr: the `cut` on MacOS is BSD compatible 

Answer (score 36):

To answer your question literally:

```
sed 's/   */:/g' | cut -d : -f 5
```

or

```
awk -F '  +' '{print $5}'
```

But that won't do if the number in brackets reaches 10, etc. If you're only interested in the numbers, you could remove everything else.

```
sed 's/[^.0-9][^.0-9]*/:/g' | cut -d : -f 6
```

Comment: yes, sure only the numbers, but only your 3rd example works correctly

Comment: @rubo77 Works for me. The first two examples do exactly what you ask in your title. Or did you want to strip off the unit as well? In that case, add `| sed 's/ .*//'` at the end of the first two examples. Of course there are many other ways to do it.

Comment: a bit shorter with `+` instead of `*`: cat test | sed 's/[^.0-9]\+/:/g' | cut -d : -f 6

Comment: @rubo77 If your sed supports it, that is. It's supported by GNU and BusyBox but not by e.g. BSD or Solaris. POSIX specifies `+` and `?` in ERE but leaves `\+` and `\?` in BRE undefined.

Comment: So the right option for columned input into cut would be -c35-38

Comment: Thanks, I now have `alias split = "sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' |cut -d ' ' -f "` in my bashrc.

Answer (score 17):

These commands will all print the last column of a space separated file:

- `awk '{print $NF}' file`

  in `awk`, `NF` is the number of fields and `$NF` is the last field.
- `perl -lane 'print $F[$#F]' file`

  `-a` splits the file on whitespace into the array `@F`, `$#F` is the number of elements in the array so `$F[$#F]` is the last element. The `-n` means read the file given on the command line and apply the script passed with `-e` to each line. `-l` just adds a newline character (`\n`) to each `print` statement.
- `sed 's/.* //g'`

  a simple regular expression that matches everything to the last space and deletes it, leaving only the last column.
- `rev file | cut -d' ' -f 1 | rev`

  `rev` reverses its output so the last field is the first, `cut` with delimiter space to print it and `rev` to reverse the text back to normal. **This won'
  t work if you have consecutive whitespace**.

Based on your input, I am guessing you don't actually want the last column but the penultimate one or the two last ones. In that case use these to print the last 2 (`8.39 Mbits/sec`):

```
awk '{print $(NF-1),$NF}' file 
perl -lane 'print "$F[$#F-1] $F[$#F]"' file 
sed 's/.* \(.* .*\)/\1/' file 
rev file | cut -d' ' -f 1,2 | rev
```

and these to print the penultimate (`8.39`):

```
awk '{print $(NF-1)}' file 
perl -lane 'print $F[$#F-1]' file 
sed 's/.* \(.*\) .*/\1/' file 
rev file | cut -d' ' -f 2 | rev
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't separate multiple occurrence of whitespaces using `cut` as per manual:

> Output fields are separated by a single occurrence of the field delimiter character.

unless the text is separated by the same amount or you use `tr` to remove excess of them.

Otherwise use alternative tools such as `awk`, `sed` or `ex`.

For example:

```
ex -s +'%norm $2Bd0' +%p +q! foo.txt
```

Replace `+q!` with `-cwq` to save the changes in-place.

Answer (score 4):

Use a perl one-liner like so:

`perl -lane 'print $F[-2]' input_file`

Explanation:

Option `-e` causes the perl interpreter to look for the script inline, rather than in a file.

Option `-n` causes the input (file or STDIN from a pipe) to be read line by line.

Option `-l` strips the input record separator (OS-dependent, newline on UNIX by default) after reading the line, and adds it at the end to every `print`

Option `-a` causes each input line to be split on whitespace into array `@F`, and `$F[-2]` is the second element counting from the end, which is the field you want. You can also use `$F[$#F-1]`, where `$#F` is the last index of the array `@F`, which is slightly less readable.

Answer (score 3):

the right option for columned input into cut would be

```
cut -c35-38
```

Comment: This is pretty hardcoded to the above example which is probably one in a million.

Comment: yes, but it shows, how you would always get the right columns. this would work even if the column you look for contains sometimes extra spaces

Comment: This cuts out the characters from the 35th position up to the 38th position, regardless of the content. To cut this way properly, you have to be sure your columns 1. are always the same width, 2. are always start at the same position. As soon as one of the rows contain `123.5 Mbits/sec` and/or download time goes up to `234.0- 235.0 sec` level, the above solution is bust. Your solution is `rigid`, the above task needs a `flexible` one.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-w` option, if your `cut` version is BSD compatible

```
$ echo "firstColumn        secondColumn   thirdColumn" | cut -w -f3
thirdColumn
```

Comment: Which it is on MacOS (which I didn't know )

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question in the body instead of the one in the heading:

```
echo '[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   768 KBytes  6.29 Mbits/sec' \
| rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

Obviously use `-f2` but the question asks for the last column so I comply.

Comment: you are right, that sentence wasn't quite exact, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.words[*-2..*].put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  1.00 MBytes  8.39 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   768 KBytes  6.29 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec   512 KBytes  4.19 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec   256 KBytes  2.10 Mbits/sec
```

Sample Output:

```
8.39 Mbits/sec
6.29 Mbits/sec
4.19 Mbits/sec
2.10 Mbits/sec
```

You might want to try Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Above, the `words` routine breaks on whitespace. Columns can be selected with square brackets: since Raku (and Perl) are zero-indexed, the second-to-last column is `*-2` and the last column is `*-1`. Here, either `words[*-2..*-1]` or `words[*-2..*]` works, the latter indicating *'give me the second-to-last column up to `*` whatever'*.

Oh, the OP only wants the second-to-last column? Titled by the last column?

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.words[*-1].put if ++$ == 1; .words[*-2].put;' file
Mbits/sec
8.39
6.29
4.19
2.10
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/words
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

I've created [a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00001.html) that adds new `-m` command-line option to `cut`, which works in the field mode and treats multiple consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.  This basically solves the OP's question in a rather efficient way.  I also submitted this patch upstream a couple of days ago, and let's hope that it will be merged into the coreutils project.

There are some [further thoughts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00011.html) about adding even more whitespace-related features to `cut`, and having some feedback about all that would be great.  I'm willing to implement more patches for `cut` and submit them upstream, which would make this utility more versatile and more usable in various real-world scenarios.