# cut column 2 from text file

Tags: text-processing, columns, cut

My text file has no delimiter to specify separator just spaces, how do I cut out column 2 to output file,

```
39    207  City and County of San Francisc   REJECTED          MAT = 0
78    412  Cases and materials on corporat   REJECTED          MAT = 0
82    431  The preparation of contracts an   REJECTED          MAT = 0
```

So output I need is

```
207
412
432
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109835/how-do-i-use-cut-to-separate-by-multiple-whitespace

Answer (score 32):

It is easiest with `awk` which treats multiple consecutive spaces as a single one, so

```
awk '{print $2}' file
```

prints

```
207
412
431
```

But obviously there are many, many other tools which will do the job, even some which were not designed for such tasks, like (GNU) `grep`:

```
grep -Po '^[^ ]+[ ]+\K[^ ]+' file
```

Answer (score 18):

Use pipes to squeeze the extra whitespaces and send your data (e.g, in `columns.txt`) into `cut`:

```
tr -s ' ' < columns.txt | cut -d" " -f2
```

In the example data you provided, a single space delimiter puts the data you want in field 5. However, if the first column was numerical and had leading spaces in order to align it to the right, you will need to adjust the field number. Squashing whitespace with `tr -s ' '` first avoids having to deal with this.

To send that output into another file use redirection:

```
tr -s ' ' < columns.txt | cut -d" " -f2 > field2.txt
```

Using the awk command you could do something like the below which recognises automatically the field you are after because there is data there(?) I need to learn more about awk.

```
awk -F' ' '{print $2}' columns.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

per `man cut`

```
 -w      Use whitespace (spaces and tabs) as the delimiter.  Consecutive
         spaces and tabs count as one single field separator.
```

shell:

```
% cat $$
39    207  City and County of San Francisc   REJECTED          MAT = 0
78    412  Cases and materials on corporat   REJECTED          MAT = 0
82    431  The preparation of contracts an   REJECTED          MAT = 0
% cut -w -f2 $$
207
412
431
%
```

Comment: right, i just updated my answer and removed `cat` ;-) thank you!

Comment: what version of `cut` has this option? definitely not mine...

Answer (score 1):

as @jimmij said, `awk '{print $2}' file` is the simplest answer.

If, for some reason, you don't want to use `awk` and insist on using `cut`, you can use `sed` to convert every instance of two or more spaces into a single tab (`cut`'s default delimiter) before piping into cut:

```
$ sed -e 's/  \+/\t/g' riley.txt | cut -f2 
207
412
431
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Perl**

```perl
perl -lane 'print $F[1];'
```

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'put .words[1];'
```

See:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109894/227738
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/555394/227738
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701811/227738

Answer (score 0):

You can still use single spaces as your delimiter, you'll just have more columns. Increase the value you give to `cut -d' ' -f` from 2 to 5, or maybe 6. Increment the number until you get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po '^[^ ]+[ ]+\K[^ ]+' file
```

Above one is very useful when Linux utilities like awk for data extraction does not work if you are changing to "root" user inside a shell script like below one:

```
sudo -i <<EOF
ps aux | grep -E -i "[l]js"  |grep -v "javaagent" | awk '{print $2}' # So awk won't work here
ps aux | grep -E -i "[l]js"  | grep -v "javaagent" | grep -Po '^[^ ]+[ ]+\K[^ ]+'
EOF
```

Comment: The only reason "`awk` won't work" in your example is that the here-document is unquoted, meaning the `$2` would be expanded by the shell to the second positional parameter. The solution is probably not to switch to a `grep` command but to either escape the `$` in `$2` as `\$2` or to simply quote the whole document by using `<<'EOF'` in place of `<<EOF`.  Also note that the task in your example is more simply carried out by `pgrep`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kusalananda. It worked like a charm.