# How to combine tr with xargs and cut to squeeze repeats

Tags: bash, git, cut, tr

The top answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109835/how-do-i-use-cut-to-separate-by-multiple-whitespace) demonstrates that `cut` can be used with `tr` to cut based on repeated spaces with

```bash
< file tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 8
```

I want to get the remotes of several Git repos in a directory and am attempting to extract the remote URL fields from each with the following:

```bash
ls | xargs -I{} git -C {} remote -vv | sed -n 'p;n' | tr -s " " | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

However, this results in (for example) the following output, where I can see that two consecutive spaces (Unicode code point 32) are retained:

```
origin  https://github.com/jik876/hifi-gan.git
origin  https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo.git
origin  https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2.git
```

(I have also using `xargs` with `tr`)

The desired output is a list of URLs, like:

```
https://github.com/jik876/hifi-gan.git
https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo.git
https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2.git
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Piping `ls` into `xargs` is very dangerous, and the output of `ls` shouldn't be used for anything except displaying file/directory listings for a human to read.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a tab, not two spaces.

You can get the same output safer with a shell loop iterating over the subdirectories in the current working directory that has a `.git` directory, then `cut` the first space-delimited field (to remove the `(fetch)` and `(push)` labels at the end that `git` adds) and then pass that through `uniq` to only show a single line for each remote+URL:

```bash
for r in ./*/.git/; do
    git -C "$r" remote -v
done | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | uniq | cut -f 2
```

The final `cut -f 2` isolates the URLs by returning the 2nd tab-delimited field.

Taking into account that `awk` treats tabs and spaces the same (unless you use a specific separator character or pattern), we can replace the trailing pipeline with a single invocation of `awk`:

```
for r in ./*/.git/; do
    git -C "$r" remote -v
done | awk '!seen[$2]++ { print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing around with `bash` and `tr` and `cut` and `xargs` and all the whitespace and word-splitting and glob issues that bash brings, you could use a language more suited to the job...and one that includes a library module for interacting with git repos.  For example, perl with the [Git::Raw](https://metacpan.org/dist/Git-Raw) module.

Here's a very simple one-liner example (although it's worth noting that `Git::Raw` is capable of much more than this and you'd probably be better off writing a stand-alone perl script that uses the module):

I've added newlines and indentation for readability. It works as-is, or all squished up on one line.

```
$ perl -MGit::Raw -l -e '
  foreach my $d (@ARGV) {
    $d =~ s/\.git$//;
    next unless -d "$d/.git";
    my $repo = Git::Raw::Repository->open($d);

    print $d;
    foreach my $r ($repo->remotes()) {
     print $r->url
    };
    print "";
  }' */.git
```

In English, that's:

1. Open each repo listed on the command line, ignoring directories that aren't actually git repos,
2. iterate over the repo's remotes and print their URLs.

Sample output. I ran the one-liner above in a directory that I sometimes use to clone various repos from github. I wrote the one-liner to print the directory name before the list of remotes belonging to that repo, and a blank line after each directory processed.

```
mgetty
https://github.com/Distrotech/mgetty.git

roxterm
https://github.com/realh/roxterm.git

zpool-iostat-viz
https://github.com/chadmiller/zpool-iostat-viz.git
```

Note: `Git::Raw` is not included with perl, it needs to be installed with `cpan` or via a distro package (e.g. on Debian etc, `apt-get install libgit-raw-perl`. Other distros probably have it too).   The module is a perl wrapper around [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) so installing it manually with CPAN will require `gcc` and the libgit2 development library & headers installed.

Also worth noting: even without `Git::Raw` parsing the output of `git` with perl (or almost any other language) is going to be a lot easier and a lot less error-prone than doing it in bash.   Perl in particular is designed for string matching and manipulation, so doing what you're trying to do in bash is trivial in perl.

---

BTW, if you prefer `python`, you may want to look at [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) instead.  On Debian etc, you can install it with `apt-get install python3-git`, and it's probably packaged for other distros too.  This one doesn't use `libgit2`, it's a wrapper around the `git` command, similar to what you're trying to do in bash.

I somehow missed this yesterday, but the `libgit2` web site says that  [pygit2](https://www.pygit2.org/) does for python what `Git::Raw` does for perl (i.e. it uses the C libgit2 library - so will be faster than forking `git` whenever needed, and avoids the risk of output-parsing problems).  Debian package is `python3-pygit2`, and it's probably packaged for other distros too.